# How do I encode HTMLTableSectionElement with Base64 and append decoded value

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64, decoding

I am saving some child nodes as Base64. This is to make passing a group of elements (nodes) around easier, ultimately saving the base64 string to a database and hopefully reading this back into the original HTML elements (nodes)

I am using `atob()` and `btoa()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

I am unable to re-use this base64 as I don't know how. I know how to convert it back into HTML.

In my application, when the user saves (clicks a button), it saves an HTML element (and children) using `btoa` and I get the 'funny' looking string.

Now, I need to reload this from the string into something HTML understand to display it in the GUI.

I use `atob(myString)` and I get an `HTMLDivElement`

I don't know how to use this. This means the following fails

My effort is (and this probably won't work in IE which is fine)

```js
  const wrapperEle = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  const destinationEle = document.getElementById("destination");
  const btn = document.getElementById("button");

  btn.addEventListener("click", performLogic);

  function performLogic() {

      destinationEle.innerHTML = null;

      const myString = btoa(wrapperEle); //encode
      const data = atob(myString);       //decode

        try {
            const node = document.createElement(data);
            destination.appendChild(node);
        } catch (e){
            alert("Failed on first effort");
        }

        try {
            destination.append(data); //appends [object HTMLDivElement]
            alert("second attempt complete");
        } catch  (e){
            alert("Failed on second effort");
        }

        try {
            destination = data; //appends [object HTMLDivELement]
            alert("third attempt complete but nothing shows");
        } catch  (e){
            alert("Failed on third effort");
        }

        try {
            destination.append(myString); //appends [object HTMLDivELement]
            alert("fourth attempt complete but nothing shows");
        } catch  (e){
            alert("Failed on fourth effort");
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>data 01</td>
  <td>data 02</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click" />

<div id="destination">
I want and expect this line of text to be replaced with the table content above after you click on the button
</div>
```

How do I recomsume the value that has been encoded and decoded? Ideally, with no JQuery or any framework, just Javascript

I've added JS as well but it won't work in IE (which is fine).

https://jsfiddle.net/uLb8okrs/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to select, encode, decode and then append an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) which is a bit more convoluted than necessary for what you are trying to achieve. Instead, just get the HTML of the element you want "copy" via the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property, then encode, decode, and replace the HTML of your destination `div`.

For example:

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const destination = document.getElementById('destination');
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const encodeDecodeAppend = () => {
  const encoded = btoa(wrapper.outerHTML); //encoded HTML
  const decoded = atob(encoded); // decoded HTML
  destination.innerHTML = decoded;
};

button.addEventListener('click', encodeDecodeAppend);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data 01</td>
      <td>data 02</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click">
<div id="destination">
  I want and expect this line of text to be replaced with the table content above after you click on the button
</div>
```

Comment: I think `innerHTML` is what he is looking for, at least the `destination` div text says so. Nice approach tough :)

Comment: @TowkirAhmed you may be right, but `outerHTML` replicates OP's attempted effort to encode, decode and append the `div` with id `wrapper` (the only thing the code sample uses `innerHTML` for is to set it to `null` for the `destination` `div`. That said, certainly makes sense to just take the `innerHTML` and is a minor substitution here if that is what OP wants.

Comment: You are right too, it just depends on what he decides to take now :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to encode the `DOM` element, that's why you get an `HTMLDivElement`.

What you should do is take the `innerHTML` of the source element and then `encode` it, then save it to database or wherever you want, and then `decode` it again and set the `innerHTML` of the target element again.

Simple as that.
Added comments in the code snippet to clear the steps as much as possible.

**Also** Notice the console output of `myString` after encoding, see how it's different from the one you found after encoding a `element` (not string)

**Note:** if you want the `#wrapper` element too, use `outerHTML` as `benvc` answered.

```js
const wrapperEle = document.getElementById("wrapper");
const destinationEle = document.getElementById("destination");
const btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", performLogic);

function performLogic() {
  destinationEle.innerHTML = null;
  let myString = btoa(wrapperEle.innerHTML); //encode /// and take the innerHTML of it to parse, not the DOM itself
  console.log(myString); // check now what it looks like, or save it in database or wherever you want.
  let data = atob(myString); //decode /// again, after decoding you just get the string type data, not a DOM type
  destinationEle.innerHTML = data; // so, now you can set the string as an innerHTML to the target element
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data 01</td>
      <td>data 02</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click" />

<div id="destination">
  I want and expect this line of text to be replaced with the table content above after you click on the button
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having relates to the fact that unlike `appendChild` in many frameworks which obscure this fact, appendChild does not accept a string as a valid argument, which is what `atob` returns your given string as; `appendChild` only accepts a Node object as a valid argument (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append for further details)

Thus, perform this operation as you wish, you have 2 options:

1) must first convert your decrypted string into a node object, then call `appendChild`

```
const data = atob(myString);    
var node = document.createElement(data);
myHtmlElement.appendChild(node);
```

2) Simply use `append` opposed to `appendChild`

```
const data = atob(myString);    
myHtmlElement.append(node);
```

- Note: `append` will not work in IE

Comment: I have updated my post, with your example and others, including working code to demonstrate this